# Integer to time format (String datatype)

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, time, formatting

I need to convert Integers like `030` to `0:30` and `1630` to `16:30`. So far I've tried using `.Insert()` method. The problem is I cannot determine whether the integer is 3 or 4-digit because it is a variable. I know I can use length or alike, but is it possible to make it a 1-line code only?

For example:

```
strTime = Convert.ToString(intTime1).Insert(2, ":") & "~" &
          Convert.ToString(intTime2).Insert(2, ":")
```

Comment: The first time you come across a string that contains a time, convert it t a `DateTime` or a `TimeSpan` variable. Then you can do arithmetic with it and you can use the `ToString` method to format it any way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [number formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) to insert the colon *and* require a value before the colon at the same time:

```
intTime1.ToString("0:00")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can I ask a follow-up question? what if i wanted to format a string for example `"1630"` should I convert it to Integer first? or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @neil: If `s` is a string and you want to insert `:` before its last two characters, you can use `s.Insert(s.Length - 2, ":")`. (If you don’t want to have to keep `s` in a variable, just wrap this into a function.)